# Why i see Lost device connection message when open gallery using image_picker?

Tags: android, ios, image, flutter

I have a problem using image_picker on flutter in real device with android. When  i open  gallery using `ImageSource.gallery` the first screen  is "Recent pictures", i can select any picture and everything fine, but if i open the [gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHW6K.jpg) i see "Lost device connection" message and white screen.

```
_procesImage(ImageSource image) async {
final ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
file = await picker.pickImage(source: image);
setState(() {}); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I beleive you're having trouble with iOS as you're talking about gallery but could you give more detail ? Is it happening on emulator or real device?

I would suggest you to doublecheck iOS specific authorizations in plist, also check if you're asking for storage permission before opening the gallery.
I had that kind of issue month ago but my library wasn't up to date and I guess updating it fixed the issue

Comment: It's in  real device and android

Answer (score 0):

Try to define methods like these and specifically point out from which location you want to access the image. Currently, it is not specified.

```
final ImagePicker imagePicker = ImagePicker();

 _imgFromCamera() async {
    final image = await imagePicker.pickImage(
        source: ImageSource.camera);
    // the further functionality here
    sendImageToServer(image);
  }

_imgFromGallery() async {
    final image = await imagePicker.pickImage(
        source: ImageSource.gallery);
    // the further functionality here
    sendImageToServer(image);
  }
```

Comment: don't work bro, i have similar methods, i send source atribute as parameter

Comment: the problem is when i open gallery, if i select a picture from recent pictures, it's works